# Half hour time zone designations when parsing input strings

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

My Php server app receives data from a mobile application, including date/time strings.

One of these strings recently caused an exception when parsing the string into a DateTime instance because the timezone was formatted like this:

2017-03-14 17:56:42GMT+05.500

```
strtotime("2017-03-14 17:56:42GMT+05.500")
```

returns false, while

```
strtotime("2017-03-14 17:56:42GMT+05")
```

returns a epoch timestamp.

What is the best practice for handling such strings?

I could grep replace and offset by half an hour on the resulting timestamp, then designate a valid (by php standards) timezone.

It feels like I'm heading for a big pile of mud - maybe some kind person have a composer library to the rescue

Comment: split the string on '.' to array, then only use the first element of the array.

Comment: Actually, converting the timezone offset format to HH:MM makes the string parsable:

strtotime("2017-03-14 17:56:42GMT+0530") results in a epoch timestamp.

I would still need to convert offset strings to that, though

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that my php app couldn't understand the 'GMT+05.500' time zone part, but *can* understand 'GMT+0530'.

I can use the regular expression below to find out if my input needs some string replacing and convert any decimal to the relevant offset in minutes

```
if(preg_match('/\+0?[\d]([,.:;_ ])([\d]{3})$/', $datetime, $matches){
    //... convert 'GMT+05.500' to 'GMT+0530' by using a switch or actual calculation
```

Currently I haven't been able to find out if user-agents will use a locale/cultural specific separator character, so I assume a range og possibilities (the ',.;:_ ' part of the regexp). Maybe there is an ISO standard for how to format this, but user-agents being user-agents... :)

'GMT+0530' will also affect the resulting epoch timestamp when using strtotime() by the proper 30 minutes, so no data is lost.

Comment: Yes, there is a well-known ISO standard.  It's ISO 8601, and looks like `2017-03-14T17:56:42+05:30`.  See also RFC3339.  If possible, go fix the mobile app so it doesn't use a nonstandard format.